# Sed condition replace read from a file

Tags: sed, input

I have 2 files, atana1 and atana2 with the following content:

```
$ cat atana1 :

location
allow 127.0.0.1;
deny all;


$ cat atana2
27.0.12.12
```

=> I wanna replace string 27.0.12.12 => 127.0.0.1 via sed and input condition from file atana2 .

I'm try command :

> sed '/127.0.0.1/r atana2' atana1

output:

```
location
allow 127.0.0.1;
27.0.12.12
deny all;
```

== >> my intention is read condition from line atana2 and replace string
127.0.0.1 via command sed .

output desire:

```
location
allow 27.0.12.12;
deny all;
```

It's not used :

```
sed -i 's/127.0.0.1/27.0.12.12/g' file.txt
```

Comment: do you mean `sed -i '/27.0.12.12/ s/27.*/127.0.0.1/' antana2` if so this replace 27.0.12.12 only on lines where it is present in atana2 ; if I understood your needs ; else please edit your post to clarify it with expected output

Comment: I'm edit my post . u can read again .

Comment: I am sorry you are receiving downvotes: You are making your efforts, I see! But the question is still not clear. Do you want to replace the IP in atana1 by the IP in atana2?

Comment: ... If yes, is there always a single line with the IP in atana2? Is the IP to be replaced in atana1 always preceded by an `allow`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do this:

```
replace="$(cat atana2)"

sed "s|127.0.0.1|$replace|" atana1
```

The double quotes in place of single quotes cause `sed` to expand the variable.

Output:

```
location
allow 27.0.12.12;
deny all;
```

Once you're sure that you have what you want:

```
sed -i "s|127.0.0.1|$replace|" atana1
```

Keep in mind that while it doesn't have any effect on this case, if there is a string such as `127102031` that appears before what you want to replace, it will replace that as well because the `.` will expand into any character. If you have a file like that in the future, be sure to replace it on the specific line such as in the following example:

```
location
allow 127.0.0.1; allow 127102031;
deny all;
127102031 127102031
```

Code:

```
sed "2s|127.0.0.1|$replace|" atana1
```

That will replace the first occurrence on the second line.

Output:

```
location
allow 27.0.12.12; allow 127102031;
deny all;
127102031 127102031
```

Multiple instances such as in the following example:

```
location
allow 127.0.0.1; allow 127102031;
deny all;
127102031 127102031
```

Second occurrence on the second line:

```
sed "2s|127.0.0.1|$replace|2" atana1
```

Output:

```
location
allow 127.0.0.1; allow 27.0.12.12;
deny all;
127102031 127102031
```

Again, you can use what I have first in this case with no issues, but this is just for future reference where the file may be different.

Comment: The problem with this is that the `.` in the OP will match any character on the left hand side and f the substitution operator. So that will also replace, e.g. 12710203. Not a problem in this specific case, but worth mentioning.

Comment: @terdon Updated to account for this if the file may be different in other cases.

Comment: Nice. Another option would be `replace="$(cat atana2 | sed 's/\./\\./g')"` to escape the `.`

Answer (score 0):

Tried with awk command

```
i=`cat `

awk -v i="$i" '{gsub("127.0.0.1",i,$0);print }'  atana1
```

output

```
location
allow 27.0.12.12;
deny all;
```